# Sometimes image in UIImageView not being displayed in scroll view

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage, ios11

I'm working on testing an app under iOS11. Everything works well, except sometimes I'm not seeing images show up in a UIScrollView. I never had this problem in iOS10.

I have a cell in a collection view that displays a UIImageView. When scrolling through the scroll view, the first two cells with their images work fine, but for the third cell/image, I get a blank white screen. If I look at the UI inspector, the image is actually loaded into the UIImageView but it is not displayed in the graphic that shows all of the views, nor is it shown on the screen.

If I focus on the UIImageView, it shows the image that has been loaded! I don't know why the image is not being displayed to the user. This problem is easily repeatable.

I'm kind of stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: share your constraints screen

Comment: Ok, do you want to see the constraints from the Storyboard? I didn't write this, but the way, I'm just trying to get it to work under iOS11.

See:https://imgur.com/6kS81zl

Also, at runtime, I see this: 

https://imgur.com/1aUcoeH

and

https://imgur.com/FQiefCh

One works and one does not.

Comment: So, it is the background of the collection view which is showing when the image fails to show. I changed the background to red and now it shows red. Sometimes the image flashes up for a second, and then the background covers it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put equalwidths and equalheights **ScrollView** to **ContainerView** and add centervertical and centerhorizontal to **UIImageView** to **ScrollView**.

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't seem to help at all.

Comment: In iOS11 problem with UIScrollView constraints. Try to play with it. First of all try to remove scroll view.

Comment: I'll try. Do you have any references to this UIScrollView constraint problem in iOS11?

Comment: here guy tried resolve this problem https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/82783

Comment: I thought iOS 11 introduced a simpler way to keep the content of a scrollview centered when zooming, as discussed in the WWDC 2017 sessions. It involves setting 
imageView.centerXAnchor.constraints(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor)
imageView.centerYAnchor.constraints(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor)

Comment: Thanks for that, nobody ever tried to help the guy out and he posted the question in July. I posted this same question over there and nobody has responded yet. Can I set these anchors in the Storyboard? I don't think I'm zooming, I'm either setting the content mode to aspect fit or aspect fill depending on the size of the image.

Comment: Hope you will fix this. Sorry don't have more ideas( Try to play with sizes, contentmodes, constraints. If you will remove scrollview and put just UIImageView and it would work it definetly problem ii n constraints. As an alternative you can try CAScrollLayer

Comment: So, it turned out that somebody had put in a call to invalidate the collection view layout every time a cell was about to be displayed, in this method:

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(OutfitCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}

I took out this call and now my collection view draws correctly. I'm not sure why someone thought this had to be done on every call to display a cell.